Simple Symfony app fail to launch on Google Cloud default php runtume
My Symfony app fails to launch on Google Cloud service. I use those in app.yaml
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
  runtime_version: "8.2"
  document_root: public

On deploy it looks like everything went successfully with composer install, assets install and etc. Then deploy stops for few minutes and error is shown:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2024-04-19T05:17:11.229Z7995.fs.2: ERROR: failed to launch: determine start command: when there is no default process a command is required

Previously I was using PHP 7 and had only those in app.yaml and it worked fine.
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

Now trying to go to PHP 8.

Problem solved. It was Procfile in the same directory that was used for Heroku  deploy. Adding it in app.yaml skip_files solved the issue.
